# AJAX как получить данные из БД по клику на ссылке?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку у меня в div-е отображалась информация, выгружаемая из БД, но без перезагрузки страницы. У меня есть документ articles.php. Здесь в script, я как раз пытаюсь загрузить div с классом output информацию из  файла article.php

**articles.php**

```html
<!--шаблон для отображения всех статей со стороны пользователя-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Мой первый блог</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <script>
    $(function ready() {
      $('a').click(function(eventObject) {
        eventObject.preventDefault();
        $('.output').load('article.php ');
      });
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Статьи</h1> 
    <a href="admin">Панель администратора</a>
    <div>
      <ul class="navigation">

        <?php foreach($articles as $a): ?>

        <div class="article">
          <li>
            <a href="article.php?id=<?=$a['id']?>">
              <?=$a[ 'title']?>Главная</a>
          </li>
          <?php endforeach ?>
      </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="output">
        <p>bla bla</p>
      </div>
      <footer>
        <p>тестовая CRM
          <br>Copyright &copy; 2015</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Файл **article.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Мой первый блог</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Мой первый блог</h1>
    <div>
      <div class="article">
        <h3><? echo $article['title']?></h3>
        <em>Опубликовано: <? echo $article['date']?></em>
        <p>
          <? echo $article[ 'content']?>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <p>Мой первый блог
        <br>Copyright &copy; 2015</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Но у меня вылазит вот такая ошибка всё время:

> Notice: Undefined index: id in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/new_blog/article.php on line 5

И из всего того, что должно выводиться (заголовок, article, date, content), выводится только заголовок `<h1>Мой первый блог</h1>`.

Ругается на файл **article.php**

```
<?php
    require_once("database.php");
    require_once("models/articles.php");
    $link = db_connect();
    $article=articles_get($link,$_GET['id']);

    include("views/article.php");
?>
```

В чём дело и как это исправить, помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: из правил хорошего тона: всегда проверяйте существует ли массив $_GET функцией ` isset = if (isset($_GET['id')){}`

Comment: ещё лучше использовать `filter_input()`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a').click(function(eventObject) {
    eventObject.preventDefault();
    $.get(
        "url_of_php_file",
        {
            id : "12",// !!example!!,zdesi nujno poslati danye, i v php file budet $_GET['id'] = 12
        }
        function(response) {
            $('div').append(response)
        }
    )
 });
```

})

Comment: Esli budeshi ispolizavati $.get to v php file budeshi poluchati danye $_GET
Esli budeshi ispolizavati $.post  to v php file budeshi poluchati danye $_POST (sry for my russian :) )

Comment: спасибо, теперь всё стало ясно @Alexandru Gojinetchi